List of icons in IMAGE_PREFIX APEX
I want to set an custom icon in the link colum as an attribute of an report, because i can only select 4 types:

Normally when you want an icon in apex, you can select them in a list. But this time i have to write the path name
<img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#app_ui/img/icons/apex-edit-view.png" class="apex-edit-view" alt="">

Does anyone know if there is a list of all the icons in this path? I want to insert the fa-bolt icon
Thanks in advance.

Best way to check what icons are available is the universal theme app. These fonts are a font library (like the "font awesome" library), they do not exist as physical images on the file system like the ones you are showing. Instead they're referenced using their class name. In the UT app link you can customize the icon to your needs and then just copy the html. In your case, for the "Link Icon" attribute in an interactive report, this can be used:
<span class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></span>

Result looks like this :

